expected value of a two dice rolling game
I am stuck on how to proceed with this question: you toss two six-sided fair dice. if the sum is 7, you win a dollar. if the sum is even, you lose a dollar. otherwise, you roll again. The question seeks the expected payoff?
I know the probability for obtaining a sum = 7 is 6/36 and the probability for sum = even is 18/36. 1-6/36-18/36=12/36 is the probability of rolling again (the sum is neither a 7 nor an even number). I also know that i have to write this as a geometric series (infinite sum). Any tips/insights would be much appreciate it.

Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post

Thanks, i have edited my question. Hopefully it is more clear and aligned to the math SE guidelines.

Denoting with $X$ the payoff you can compute its expected value as:$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{1}{6}\cdot 1\$ + \frac{1}{2} \cdot (-1\$) + \frac{1}{3}\mathbb{E}[X] \rightarrow \frac{2}{3} \mathbb{E}[X] = -\frac{1}{3} \$.$$
Therefore $\mathbb{E}[X] = -0.5\$ $

Let $E$ denoted the expected payoff per roll.
Considering only the rolls that either give us a dollar or we lose a dollar, there are $6+18=24$ possibilities. $\frac{6}{24}=\frac{1}{4}$ of those win us a dollar. $\frac{18}{24}=\frac{3}{4}$ lose us  a dollar. Thus,
$$E=\frac{1}{4}(+1\$)+\frac{3}{4}(-1\$)=-0.5\$$$
If you're interested, here's a simply python program to verify this result:
import random
n=100000
T=0
def result():
    d_1=random.randint(1,6)
    d_2=random.randint(1,6)
    if d_1+d_2==7:
        return int(1)
    if (d_1+d_2)%2==0:
        return int(-1)
    else:
        return result() #Roll again

for i in range(1,n):
    T=T+result()

print("Average value after 100000 games is "+str(T/n))

